# How does the libuv implementation of *non-blockingness* work exactly?

Tags: c, asynchronous, io, event-loop, libuv

So I have just discovered that [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) is a fairly small library as far as C libraries go (compare to FFmpeg). I have spent the past 6 hours reading through the source code to get a feel for the event loop at a deeper level. But still not seeing where the "nonblockingness" is implemented. Where some event interrupt signal or whatnot is being invoked in the codebase.

I have been using Node.js for over 8 years so I am familar with how to *use* an async non-blocking event loop, but I never actually looked into the implementation.

My question is twofold:

1. *Where* exactly is the "looping" occuring within libuv?
2. What are the key steps in each iteration of the loop that make it **non-blocking** and **async**.

So we start with a hello world example. All that is required is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>

int main() {
  uv_loop_t *loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
  uv_loop_init(loop); // initialize datastructures.
  uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT); // infinite loop as long as queue is full?
  uv_loop_close(loop);
  free(loop);
  return 0;
}
```

The key function which I have been exploring is `uv_run`. The `uv_loop_init` function essentially initializes data structures, so not too much fancness there I don't think. But the real magic seems to happen with `uv_run`, *somewhere*. A high level set of code snippets from the libuv repo is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/0aa911f53092f2b25140ae1cc2e18daf), showing what the `uv_run` function calls.

Essentially it seems to boil down to this:

```
while (NOT_STOPPED) {
  uv__update_time(loop)
  uv__run_timers(loop)
  uv__run_pending(loop)
  uv__run_idle(loop)
  uv__run_prepare(loop)
  uv__io_poll(loop, timeout)
  uv__run_check(loop)
  uv__run_closing_handles(loop)
  // ... cleanup
}
```

Those functions are in the gist.

- `uv__run_timers`: runs timer callbacks? loops with `for (;;) {`.
- `uv__run_pending`: runs regular callbacks? loops through queue with `while (!QUEUE_EMPTY(&pq)) {`.
- `uv__run_idle`: *no source code*
- `uv__run_prepare`: *no source code*
- `uv__io_poll`: does io polling? (can't quite tell what this means tho). Has 2 loops: `while (!QUEUE_EMPTY(&loop->watcher_queue)) {`, and `for (;;) {`,

And then we're done. And the program exists, because there is no "work" to be done.

So I think I have answered the first part of my question after all this digging, and the looping is specifically in these 3 functions:

1. `uv__run_timers`
2. `uv__run_pending`
3. `uv__io_poll`

But not having implemented anything with `kqueue` or multithreading and having dealt relatively little with file descriptors, I am not quite following the code. This will probably help out others along the path to learning this too.

So the second part of the question is **what are the key steps in these 3 functions that implement the nonblockingness**? Assuming this is where all the looping exists.

Not being a C expert, does `for (;;) {` "block" the event loop? Or can that run indefinitely and somehow other parts of the code are jumped to from OS system events or something like that?

So `uv__io_poll` calls `poll(...)` in that endless loop. I don't think is non-blocking, is that correct? That seems to be all it mainly does.

Looking into `kqueue.c` there is also a `uv__io_poll`, so I assume the `poll` implementation is a fallback and `kqueue` on Mac is used, which is non-blocking?

So is that it? Is it just looping in `uv__io_poll` and each iteration you can add to the queue, and as long as there's stuff in the queue it will run? I still don't see how it's non-blocking and async.

Can one outline similar to this how it is async and non-blocking, and which parts of the code to take a look at? Basically, I would like to see where the "free processor idleness" exists in libuv. Where is the processor ever free in the call to our initial `uv_run`? If it is free, how does it get reinvoked, like an event handler? (Like a browser event handler from the mouse, an interrupt). I feel like I'm looking for an interrupt but not seeing one.

I ask this because I want to implement an MVP event loop in C, but just don't understand how nonblockingness actually is implemented. Where the rubber meets the road.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that trying to understand libuv is getting in your way of understanding how reactors (event loops) are implemented in C, and it is this that you need to understand, as opposed to the exact implementation details behind libuv.

(Note that when I say "in C", what I really means is "at or near the system call interface, where userland meets the kernel".)

All of the different backends (select, poll, epoll, etc) are, more-or-less, variations on the same theme.  They block the current process or thread until there is work to be done, like servicing a timer, reading from a socket, writing to a socket, or handling a socket error.

When the current process is blocked, it literally is not getting any CPU cycles assigned to it by the OS scheduler.

Part of the issue behind understanding this stuff IMO is the poor terminology: async, sync in JS-land, which don't really describe what these things are.  Really, in C, we're talking about non-blocking vs blocking I/O.

When we read from a blocking file descriptor, the process (or thread) is blocked -- prevented from running -- until the kernel has something for it to read; when we write to a blocking file descriptor, the process is blocked until the kernel accepts the entire buffer.

In non-blocking I/O, it's exactly the same, except the kernel won't stop the process from running when there is nothing to do: instead, when you read or write, it tells you how much you read or wrote (or if there was an error).

The select system call (and friends) prevent the C developer from having to try and read from a non-blocking file descriptor over and over again -- select() is, in effect, a blocking system call that unblocks when any of the descriptors or timers you are watching are ready.  This lets the developer build a loop around select, servicing any events it reports, like an expired timeout or a file descriptor that can be read.  *This is the event loop.*

So, at its very core, what happens at the C-end of a JS event loop is roughly this algorithm:

```
while(true) {
  select(open fds, timeout);
  did_the_timeout_expire(run_js_timers());
  for (each error fd)
    run_js_error_handler(fdJSObjects[fd]);
  for (each read-ready fd)
    emit_data_events(fdJSObjects[fd], read_as_much_as_I_can(fd));
  for (each write-ready fd) {
    if (!pendingData(fd))
      break;
    write_as_much_as_I_can(fd);
    pendingData = whatever_was_leftover_that_couldnt_write; 
  }
}
```

FWIW - I have actually written an event loop for v8 based around select(): it really is this simple.

It's important also to remember that JS always runs to completion. So, when you call a JS function (via the v8 api) from C, your C program doesn't do anything until the JS code returns.

NodeJS uses some optimizations like handling pending writes in a separate pthreads, but these all happen in "C space" and you shouldn't think/worry about them when trying to understand this pattern, because they're not relevant.

You might also be fooled into the thinking that JS isn't run to completion when dealing with things like async functions -- but it absolutely is, 100% of the time -- if you're not up to speed on this, do some reading with respect to the event loop and the micro task queue.  Async functions are basically a syntax trick, and their "completion" involves returning a Promise.

Answer (score 7):

I just took a dive into `libuv`'s source code, and found at first that it seems like it does a lot of setup, and not much actual event handling.

Nonetheless, a look into `src/unix/kqueue.c` [reveals](http://%20https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/815b0766eddf1ef6ebc9481c432b59d0477eb74d/src/unix/kqueue.c#L99) some of the inner mechanics of event handling:

```
int uv__io_check_fd(uv_loop_t* loop, int fd) {
  struct kevent ev;
  int rc;

  rc = 0;
  EV_SET(&ev, fd, EVFILT_READ, EV_ADD, 0, 0, 0);
  if (kevent(loop->backend_fd, &ev, 1, NULL, 0, NULL))
    rc = UV__ERR(errno);

  EV_SET(&ev, fd, EVFILT_READ, EV_DELETE, 0, 0, 0);
  if (rc == 0)
    if (kevent(loop->backend_fd, &ev, 1, NULL, 0, NULL))
      abort();

  return rc;
}
```

The file descriptor polling is done here, "setting" the event with `EV_SET` (similar to how you use `FD_SET` before checking with `select()`), and the handling is done via the `kevent` handler.

This is specific to the `kqueue` style events (mainly used on BSD-likes a la MacOS), and there are many other implementations for different Unices, but they all use the same function name to do nonblocking IO checks. See [here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/37a8affbd319209fd0d0d96ee4e3002c8ecc5076/src/unix/linux-core.c#L180) for another implementation using `epoll`.

To answer your questions:

1) **Where exactly is the "looping" occuring within libuv?**

The `QUEUE` data structure is used for storing and processing events. This queue is filled by the platform- and IO- specific event types you register to listen for. Internally, it uses a clever linked-list using only an array of two `void *` pointers ([see here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/e4087dedf837f415056a45a838f639a3d9dc3ced/src/queue.h#L21)):

`typedef void *QUEUE[2];`

I'm not going to get into the details of this list, all you need to know is it implements a queue-like structure for adding and popping elements.

Once you have file descriptors in the queue that are generating data, the asynchronous I/O code mentioned earlier will pick it up. The `backend_fd` within the `uv_loop_t` structure is the generator of data for each type of I/O.

2) **What are the key steps in each iteration of the loop that make it non-blocking and async**?

`libuv` is essentially a wrapper (with a nice API) around the real workhorses here, namely `kqueue, epoll, select`, etc. To answer this question completely, you'd need a fair bit of background in kernel-level file descriptor implementation, and I'm not sure if that's what you want based on the question.

The short answer is that the underlying operating systems all have built-in facilities for non-blocking (and therefore async) I/O. How each system works is a little outside the scope of this answer, I think, but I'll leave some reading for the curious:

https://www.quora.com/Network-Programming-How-is-select-implemented?share=1

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to keep in mind is that work must be added to libuv's queues using its API; one cannot just load up libuv, start its main loop, and then code up some I/O and get async I/O.

The queues maintained by libuv are managed by looping. The infinite loop in `uv__run_timers` isn't actually infinite; notice that the first check verifies that a soonest-expiring timer exists (presumably, if the list is empty, this is NULL), and if not, breaks the loop and the function returns. The next check breaks the loop if the current (soonest-expiring) timer hasn't expired. If neither of those conditions breaks the loop, the code continues: it restarts the timer, calls its timeout handler, and then loops again to check more timers. Most times when this code runs, it's going to break the loop and exit, allowing the other loops to run.

What makes all this non-blocking is the caller/user following the guidelines and API of libuv: adding your work to queues, and allowing libuv to perform its work on those queues. Processing-intensive work may block these loops and other work from running, so it's important to break your work into chunks.

Answer (score 0):

btw, uv__run_idle, uv__run_check, uv__run_prepare 's source code is defined on src/unix/loop-watcher.c